# Read many images in a folder by using python

Tags: python, image, python-2.7

I'm using python for the first time : I have  a folder that contains hundred of images and i need to read the time of each on. 
I know how to read the time of an image but i dont know how to open each image in this folder by order.
thanks for helping

Comment: Post what you've tried so far...

Comment: what is `the time`? Creation date? Modify date?

Comment: And the time of each file would be written where?...do you mean in the filename itself or metadata of each file or what? and what order you mean?...you have to explain more what you wants by editing your question

Comment: What do you mean by "open image" (what do you want to do with it) and "by order" (alphabetically?, ...)? Also, have you already googled the topic?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print them in alphabetical order, you can use the following code. With `if file.endswith(".png")` you will only get `.png` files. This is good if you have any other type of files in the same directory.

```
import os, os.path, time
for file in os.listdir("/folder_name"):
    if file.endswith(".png"):
        print str(file) + " - Creation date: " + str(time.ctime(os.path.getctime(file)))
```

Output:

```
IMG_01.png - Creation date: Thu Nov 12 09:33:13 2015
```